# Batch file doesn't work properly unless I'm watching it

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd, copy, rename

I've searched for a solution to my issue, but it's strange and I can't exactly figure out where it's going wrong.

I have a batch file that seems pretty straightforward. In a directory that has two files, it's supposed to delete one, copy the other, then rename it to what the file just deleted was named. Everything seems to work properly except for the renaming. It almost appears that the script runs twice, but I can't find any actual evidence of this. Please see below:

```
SET filepath="\\server-name\directory with a space\"
SET oldFile=filename.csv
SET curFile=filename_*.csv

REM ===Delete current filename.csv===
IF EXIST %filepath%%oldFile% DEL %filepath%%oldFile%

REM ===Copy all versions of .csv files that begin with filename_ to the Archive folder===
IF EXIST %filepath%%curFile% COPY /y %filepath%%curFile% %filepath%%Archive

REM ===Rename the .csv file beginning with filename_ to filename.csv===
IF EXIST %filepath%%curFile% RENAME %filepath%%curFile% %oldFile%
```

If I run this manually, it appears to work fine. However, when I let it be called from a Scheduled Task, it appears to run twice... that is, it deletes the filename.csv, copies the filename_*.csv to the correct place, but then seems to delete the second file rather than rename it.

As I said, I'm really unclear on what is actually being done. I've tried logging the results in an output file, but there isn't anything helpful within.

Can anyone see anything I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For testing insert an `echo %filepath%%oldFile%` - it outputs `"\\server-name\directory with a space\"filename.csv` - propably not what you wanted. Answer of Magoo shows the correct quotation syntax for `set`.

Comment: Thank you so far to zett42, lit, and Magoo for the help with the quote mark positions and better practices. I feel like this helps a great deal, even if in the end it doesn't fully resolve the root issue. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally discovered the solution to this. Turns out there was a copy of the task running on an older server that our new environment had been migrated from. It was running at the exact same time as the one on the new server, which is why it would run perfectly fine any way I tried to run it before or after the time the task was set to run. Disabling the old version of the task resolved the issue.

Thank you to those who provided feedback and suggestions on my commands!

Answer (score 1):

Examine

```
IF EXIST %filepath%%curFile% COPY /y %filepath%%curFile% %filepath%%Archive
```

Note that `archive` appears to have a leading `%` - is this meant to be a directory "archive" or is `archive` set to something you're not showing us and therefore it should be `...%filepath%%Archive%`

The consequence of the (?missing/stray `%`) is that the file would be copied to a file named `archive` or to a directory named `archive` if that directory already exists.

Personally, I'd use

```
SET "filepath=\\server-name\directory with a space"
```

where the quotes delimit the string to be assigned (so no stray trailing spaces are assigned to the variable) and then construct the source/destination names using "%var1%\%var2%" which ensures no double-`"` appear and the directory is obvious (but this is a matter of style).

Comment: It is a subfolder. For example \\server-name\directory with a space\Archive.

I see that stray leading '%' sign you spotted (good eye!), but it does do the copy correctly. What seems to happen is that it deletes the old file (if it exists), copies the current file to the Archive subfolder, but then, rather than rename it, seems to also delete it from the current folder. That's part of what has me so confused.

Comment: Well, it seems to work for me using my simulation of your situation. Are you sure that `oldfile` does not exist in your `filepath` directory after the `rename`? Perhaps `dir filename*.csv` both before and after the `if exist...rename...` line might provide a clue? I tried with multiple `filename_*.csv` files, which yielded the appropriate "duplicate filename or not found" messages but still left `filename.csv` in residence. Are you sure that you're not simply misinterpreting the error messages?

Comment: Yes, when I leave it alone and let it run from the Task, I end up with no filename.csv. For example:

Let's say I have `filename.csv` in the "Base Folder" folder from the day before. So the oldFile is `\\Server\Base Folder\filename.csv`. A new file is created today that is `filename_2017.12.28.11.15.csv`. Both are in the same folder.

If I let the script run on it's own, I find the `filename_2017.12.28.11.15.csv` file in \\Server\Base Folder\Archive, and no files at all in Base Folder. I can then copy the file from the Archive, manually run the task again, and it runs perfectly.

Comment: What I mean by that last line is copy the file from the Archive back to the Base Folder, then run the task again, and it works.

What I'm stumped on is why it seems to run fine manually, but won't do the rename when I let the same exact script run on its own via the Scheduled Task.

Answer (score 1):

It is a best practice to quote paths. In this case, where a space is involved, it is a requirement. It is easier to omit quoting from the varaiable definition and provide them where needed when the variable is used.

```
SET filepath=\\server-name\sharename\directory with a space\
IF EXIST "%filepath%%oldFile%" DEL "%filepath%%oldFile%"
```

In my experience, it is best to leave the directory at the end of a path without the trailing backslash. Also, a UNC path should have a sharename.

```
SET "filepath=\\server-name\sharename\directory with a space"
IF EXIST "%filepath%\%oldFile%" (DEL "%filepath%\%oldFile%")
```